# Printing a template on Reverse side

Tags: printing

I have a printer set-up and I am constantly printing contracts etc, and I need it to be able to print a template on the reverse side with all the terms and conditions.

I have no idea where to start with this one, it's stumped me...

Thanks in advance to anybody who can offer any advice what so ever.

Regards

Henry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your printer has double sided printing, you could try inserting the terms and conditions in the appropriate page(s) and then choose double sided printing from your print dialog. If that doesn't do it, and if your terms and conditions do not vary across the contracts you are printing, you could print a batch of the terms and conditions, and then load those pages in when it's time to print a contract.

Comment: yes !!! There are 2 printer trays, I said we should just print them as a water mark on the reverse of all the pages in tray 1, but I wondered if there was any software that could make this happen automatically.

Comment: I think this is a hardware feature of printers, so the software shouldn't do it.  If your printer supports this feature, then it should be available from your stock printer dialog box.

Comment: yea I can do double sided printing, just not a template to reverse. I am sure that it would be possible to make software that would insert the page between every page in the printing spool...

Comment: Ok, now I see.  Not sure of any software to do this.  It sounds close to a mail merge, which is a stock feature of word processors, but I don't know if you can repurpose a mail merge to do this.

Comment: ok, thanks for your help... Maybe the printing on reverse on whole page stack might be easier